# необходимо слово разделить на символы

Tags: python, python-3.x

подскажите, из файла подается строка текста, например "ABCDEF". я считываю в список

```
code = []
with open('text.txt') as file:
    for items in file:
        code.append(items)
```

мне нужно чтобы в code был каждый символ отдельно, те ["A","B","C","D","E","F"]

применяю `list(code)`, но все равно в списке 1 элемент ["ABCDEF"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
text = "ABCDEF"
data = list(text)
print(data)
```

все работает, а вам не надо делать `append` - ведь вы сразу все и добавляете не разбивая

сделайте вот так:

```
code = []
with open('text.txt') as file:
    for items in file:
        code += list(items)

print(code)
```

Comment: `code += list(items)` -> `code.extend(items)`. Первая конструкция может привести к квадратичному алгоритму.

Answer (score 0):

Ну можно ещё так:

```
a='ABCDEF'
s=[]
for i in a:
    s.append(i)
print(s)
```

У переменной `а` значение `ABCDEF`, компьютер выводит `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']`

Answer (score 0):

Читать по строкам, разбивать на символы:

```
with open('text.txt') as file:
    code = [с for line in file for c in line]

print(code)
```